# Calculate the curve that is orthogonal to the given curve?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation *$y = Cy^{2} - 3x^{4}$* find a curve orthogonal to the given curve

The steps I did so far are:

Isolating C: *$C = (y + 3x^{4})/y^{2}$*

Using symbolab's implicit differentiation calculator: *$y' = -(12x^{3}y)/(-6x^{4}-y)$*

Taking the negative reciprocal: *$y' = (-6x^{4} -y)/(12x^{3}y)$*

Simplifying the right hand side: *$y'= -x/(2y) - 1/(12x^{3})$*

At this point I'm completely confused as the *y* is in the denominator and *y'* is already isolated so separation of variables and Bernoulli's does not seem to work. Is there another way to do this equation or did I just make a simple mistake?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use an implicit calculator. Simply differentiate the equation :
$$C=\frac{1}{y}+\frac{3x^4}{y^2}$$
$$0=-\frac{1}{y^2}dy-\frac{6x^4}{y^3}dy+\frac{12x^3}{y^2}dx=-\left(\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{6x^4}{y^3}\right)dy+\frac{12x^3}{y^2}dx$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{12x^3}{y^2}}{\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{6x^4}{y^3}}=\frac{12x^3y}{y+6x^4}$$
To avoid confusion, one use a different symbol for the orthogonal function :$\quad Y(x)$
$$\frac{dY}{dx}=-\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}=-\frac{Y+6x^4}{12x^3Y}$$
That is what you found. So, there is no mistake in your calculus.
$$Y\frac{dY}{dx}=-\frac{1}{12x^3}Y-\frac{x}{2}$$
This ODE is an Abell's differential equation of the second kind. One know that all Abell's equations are not solvable in term of a finite number of standard functions. As far as I can see, this is the case for the above ODE. So, I think that one cannot find a closed form for the general solution. Use numerical calculus to solve it and draw the family of orthogonal curves.